# Creating an Outlook Add-in in Visual Studio 2013 from a Outlook VBA project (.OTM)

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2013, outlook, outlook-addin

I have a VBA Project in Outlook 2013 (VbaProject.OTM) that has several macros and currently works well. I would like to create a COM Add-in for Outlook in Visual Studio 2013 for this Project. What is the best/quickest way of getting this done? I have been searching through for information but most of them specify exporting the modules and importing it back in visual studio. Is it possible to do it on a project level? Also how do I add references that I had in Outlook 2013's VBA project to my visual studio 2013 project? Kindly let me know.

Cheers.

Comment: I hope you get a helpful answer, I have been working on the same problem quite a lot and have given up. Even code-sniplets that work in the otm do not work in visual Studio, so even if you could Import "all of it" you would have to work on most of the code to get it running.

Comment: At the moment I am just trying to transfer one module after the other and clear out the errors. Not sure if there are other ways to do it or not.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to manually convert all of your VBA code to VB.NET; I know of no existing converter.  The languages are very similar but still have a great of differences (especialily with variable declaration).

I'm not sure what kind of references you are using, but you can still set references to COM objects in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

As Eric mentioned, there is no tool for converting your VBA code into an add-in. Need to create an Outlook add-in from scratch.

You may find the [Converting a VBA Macro to C# 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/09/28/converting-a-vba-macro-to-c-4-0.aspx) blog post helpful.

Comment: great link. I think its also worth checking OutlookCode website which used to have a few good links on this topic. Also there is a two part MSDN article which is a couple of years old on this topic. most of the advice is best practise and is still relevant.